# How to get the result of TrigFactor in terms of Cos

Tags: trigonometry

If I use TrigFactor, it gives the result in terms of Sin:

```
In[483]:=
expr := Cos[x] + Sin[x]
TrigFactor[expr]

Out[485]=Sqrt[2]*Sin[Pi/4 + x]
```

What I want to get is

```
Sqrt[2]*Cos[-Pi/4 + x]
```

Using ReplaceAll doesn't help, since it does the replacement, but then converts back to Sin.

```
In[489]:=
expr := Cos[x] + Sin[x]
TrigFactor[expr] /. Sin[t_] -> Cos[t - Pi/2]

Out[490]=Sqrt[2] Sin[Pi/4 + x]
```

Comment: Try e.g.: `TrigFactor[expr] /. Sin[Pi/4 + t_] -> HoldForm@Cos[t - Pi/4]`

Comment: `(((expr // TrigFactor) /. Sin[x_] :> Inactive[Cos][x - Pi/2]) // 
   Activate) /. Cos[x_] :> Cos[-x]` The last replacement is not necessary if you are satisfied with the negative of the desired argument.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
Simplify[TrigFactor[Cos[x] + Sin[x]], 
 ComplexityFunction -> (Count[{#1}, _Sin, Infinity] &)]

(*  Sqrt[2] Cos[1/4 (\[Pi] - 4 x)]  *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 7):

Use [`RuleDelayed (:>)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) instead of [`Rule (->)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) (see: [tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html)):

```
TrigFactor[expr] /. Sin[t_] :> (Cos[t - Pi/2])
```

> ```
>  Sqrt[2] Cos[π/4 - x]
> ```

Alternatively,

```
TrigFactor[expr] /. Sin -> (Cos[# - π/2] &)
```

> ```
>  Sqrt[2] Cos[π/4 - x]
> ```